# Automatic Adjust of Y axis values using slider on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider, jupyter

I was working on making a graph that displays the full line by keping x axis constant and left axis adjusting. I am calculating the cost to produce egg tray with multiple variables.

Using jupyter notebook with ipywidgets as widgets i was able to get the answer.

[jypyter auto adjusting y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkMuU.png)

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

%matplotlib nbagg

x = np.linspace(50000, 80000, 30000)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,4))
plt.suptitle('Cost To Produce')

def production_cost(carton_percent,assorted_percent,white_percent,dry_eggtray_weight,electric_cost,ebiogas_sold,skilled_labor,manual_labor):
    ax.clear()
    total_paper_weight = x*dry_eggtray_weight/1000
    
    carton_price = total_paper_weight*carton_percent*1.9/100
    assorted_price = total_paper_weight*assorted_percent*4.25/100
    white_price = total_paper_weight*white_percent*10/100
    
    burner_consumption = (x+8679)/17.3
    electric_consumption = (x+11074)/19.1
    
    skilledlabor_cost = skilled_labor*6*346/7+skilled_labor*6*3.5*54/7
    manuallabor_cost = manual_labor*6*290/7+manual_labor*6*3.5*36/7
    
    rawmats_price = carton_price + assorted_price + white_price
    burner_price = burner_consumption*2.2*ebiogas_sold
    electric_price = electric_consumption*electric_cost
    labor_price = skilledlabor_cost + manuallabor_cost
    cellophane_price = x*13/(140*2)
    maintenance_price = 2000
    admin_price = 4000
    
    overall_price = rawmats_price + burner_price + electric_price + labor_price + cellophane_price + maintenance_price + admin_price
    y = overall_price/x
    
    ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.set_xlabel('Egg Tray Production')
    ax.set_ylabel('Cost per Tray')
    plt.show()
    
carton_percent = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=100, value=37.5, description='% Carton:')
assorted_percent = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=100, value=37.5, description='% Assorted:')
white_percent = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=100, value=25, description='% White:')

dry_eggtray_weight = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=90, value=80, description='Dry Try (g):')

electric_cost = widgets.FloatSlider(min=6, max=20, value=11.37, description='Elec Cost:')
ebiogas_sold = widgets.FloatSlider(min=6, max=20, value=6.7, description='EBio SellP:')

skilled_labor = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=12, value=6, description='Skilled C:')
manual_labor = widgets.IntSlider(min=0, max=16, value=12, description='Manual C:')


widgets.interactive(production_cost, carton_percent=carton_percent, assorted_percent=assorted_percent, white_percent=white_percent, dry_eggtray_weight=dry_eggtray_weight, electric_cost=electric_cost, ebiogas_sold=ebiogas_sold, skilled_labor=skilled_labor, manual_labor=manual_labor)
```

But using python idle, i wasnt able to copy the result

I tried narrowing variables so it wouldnt be hard to trace. So i tried this code with widgets from matplotlib directly. but only the drawing or graph is moving and both x and y axis is steady. I have tried autoscale but it does not work. Like ax.autoscale

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button


# The parametrized function to be plotted
def f(x,electric_cost,ebiogas_sold):
    
    burner_consumption = (x+8679)/17.3
    electric_consumption = (x+11074)/19.1
    
    burner_price = burner_consumption*2.2*ebiogas_sold
    electric_price = electric_consumption*electric_cost
    
    overall_price =  burner_price + electric_price
    
    return overall_price/x

x = np.linspace(50000, 80000, 30001)

# Define initial parameters
init_electric_cost = 11.37
init_ebiogas_sold = 6.7

# Create the figure and the line that we will manipulate
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, f(x, init_electric_cost, init_ebiogas_sold), lw=2)
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis="y", tight=True)
ax.set_xlabel('Egg Tray Produced [pcs]')

# adjust the main plot to make room for the sliders
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

# Make a vertically oriented slider to control the cost of electricity
electric_cost = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
electric_cost_slider = Slider(
    ax=electric_cost,
    label="Electric Cost [pesos]",
    valmin=0,
    valmax=20,
    valinit=init_electric_cost,
)

# Make a vertically oriented slider to control the cost of biogas converted to power and then sold
biogas_cost = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.25, 0.0225, 0.63])
biogas_cost_slider = Slider(
    ax=biogas_cost,
    label="Biogas Power Sold [pesos]",
    valmin=0,
    valmax=20,
    valinit=init_ebiogas_sold,
    orientation="vertical"
)

# The function to be called anytime a slider's value changes
def update(val):
    line.set_ydata(f(x, electric_cost_slider.val, biogas_cost_slider.val))
    #fig.canvas.draw_idle()

# register the update function with each slider
electric_cost_slider.on_changed(update)
biogas_cost_slider.on_changed(update)

# Create a `matplotlib.widgets.Button` to reset the sliders to initial values.
resetax = fig.add_axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', hovercolor='0.975')

def reset(event):
    biogas_cost_slider.reset()
    electric_cost_slider.reset()
button.on_clicked(reset)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer.
I just have to change the limits of my Y

My changes are highlighted as BOLD

I dont know how to properly construct yet. so ill just paste the screenshot of changes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCtuA.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBx3e.png)